# Store functions as elements of an array php

Tags: php, arrays, function

Is it possible store a few functions in an array by reference or by anonymous function?

For example:

```
 $array = [fun1, function(){ /*do something*/ }, fun3];
```

where fun1 and fun3 are defined as

```
 function fun1(){/*do something*/}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your PHP version is **`>= 5.3`** you'll be able to harness anonymous functions and regular functions in your array:

```
function yourFunction($string){
    echo $string . " : by reference";
};

$array = array(
    'a' => function($string){
        echo $string;
    },
    'b' => 'yourFunction',
);
```

You can use the [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) or [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) functions.

```
call_user_func($array['a'], 'I love things');
call_user_func($array['b'], 'I love things');
```

---

Or As [*@Andrew stated in the comments*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557538/store-functions-as-elements-of-an-array-php/37557601?noredirect=1#comment62603730_37557601) too, you could call it as the following:

```
$array['a']('I love things');
$array['b']('I love things');
```

---

If you'd like to read more about these callback methods, it's filed under the [`callback` pseudo-type documentation on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) and it is well worth a read!

Comment: Don't you mean `> 5.3`?  Also, I think you could just call it like `$array['a']('I love things')`, no?

Comment: Hahah @Andrew yes I did! It's too early here :|

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that, however you can't store the function as *literal*, but instead you have to refer to it by its name:

```
$array = ['fun1', function () { /*do something*/ }, 'fun3'];

foreach ($array as $fun) {
    $fun();
}
```

Note that because it's *by name*, you'll have to use the *fully qualified name* should your function happen to be in a namespace; e.g. `'foo\bar\baz'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, with anonymous function and by reference

```
 $test = array();

 $test['testFunction'] = function($message) {
  echo $message;
 };


 function show_msg($message) {
     echo $message;
 }

 $test['testFunction2'] = 'show_msg';

 call_user_func($test['testFunction'], 'Hi!');

 call_user_func($test['testFunction2'], 'Hello world!');
?>
```